# Experiments/papers for temperature dependence of persistent supercurrent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

According to the BCS theory of superconductivity, the superfluid density decreases at warming. Hence, an eternal supercurrent must also decrease at temperature increase. However, all observations indicate that the supercurrent is stable despite all temperature variations below critical temperature. The theory/experiment paradox is open. Does someone know papers about **direct experiments** for the temperature dependence of persistent supercurrents in superconductors?